# Inner product on $C[0,1]$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inner-products

Let $V = \mathcal{C}[0,1]$ with inner product $\langle v,w\rangle =\int_{0}^1 v(x)w(x) \mathrm{d}x$. Find a functional $f\in V^*$ for which there does not exist a vector $v\in V$ satisfying $f(w) = \langle v,w\rangle$.

I tried to use $f(w) = w(\frac{1}{2})$, but I cannot find a contradiction. Any help?

Comment: How about $\delta_0$?

Comment: @Tryss what do you mean by $\delta_0$?

Comment: The dirac at 0. And to prove there exist no function v, consider the sequence $w_n(x) = 1-nx$ on $[0,1/n]$ and $0$ elsewhere

Comment: @Ian why the integral of $vw_n$ is at most $M/n$?

Comment: Because $w_n$ is at most $1$ and is only nonzero on $[0,1/n]$, while $v$ is at most $M$ (this is how I defined $M$).

Comment: But $\delta_0$ is not continuous on $V$ with the norm coming from the inner product.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Oh, you're right, the norm should be the induced norm from the inner product. In that case the problem is that $C[0,1]$ is not complete with respect to this norm: there are $L^2[0,1]$ functions which have no continuous representative, and these are in $V^*$ (in the sense of Riesz representation as usual). In this case functions with a jump discontinuity in the interior will all form examples.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre :  Indeed, I believed it was the $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ space with the usual norm

Answer (score 0):

Try something like
$$
f(w)=\int_0^{a}w(x)\,dx\text{ where }0<a<1.
$$
$$
|f(w)|=\Bigl|\int_0^aw(x)\,dx\Bigr|\le\Bigl(\int_0^a|w(x)|^2\,dx\Bigr)^{1/2}\Bigl(\int_0^adx\Bigr)^{1/2}\le a^{1/2}\,\|w\|,
$$
so that $f$ is continuous on $V$ with the norm coming from the inner product ($\|w\|^2=\langle w,w\rangle$.)
Let $v(x)=1$ if $0\le x\le a$, $v(x)=0$ if $a<x\le1$. Then $f(w)=\langle w,v\rangle$, but $v\not\in V$.

Comment: One thing that needs to be checked is that there isn't a continuous representative of $v$ in $L^2$. There isn't, as it turns out, but this is not a completely trivial fact. If you had used, say, $v=1_{\mathbb{Q}}$, there would be a continuous representative in $L^2$, namely $0$, but $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is certainly not in $V$.

Comment: Yes, of course, but I leave it to the OP. The functional generated by $\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is generated also by the constant function $0$, so that it is not a valid example.